# How to query objects in array and return an object?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I try to query the data and hope it can return a object.

My data structure looks like this:

[image]

I want to query the `movie` array the `enName` is `Terminal` and return which is the query conditions objects.

I try to use

```
db.getCollection('Keelung').find({"movie":{"enName": 'Terminal'}})
```

in Robo3T shell, it will return `Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms`

Then I think it should loop the element `movie` array

So I try this

```
db.getCollection('Keelung').find({movie: {$elemMatch: {enName:'Terminal'}}})
```

But it will return the document `Keelung` the result almost like `db.getCollection('Keelung').find({})` that is not what I want.

I have no idea what should I try next.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `db.movie.find({ "enName": "Terminal"})` ?

Comment: Yes i try it. Its no working.I think the reason is `enName` is under my movie array

Comment: I fix it, thenks the duplicate information.